# how to deploy android app on server and additional convert django to apk

Tags: android, django, android-studio

I am very new to android application development; I want to know how to deploy an app and how much it cost to deploy
as an additional question, I am fairly good at Django so I want to ask can I convert the Django web application into apk file and how; just share an example link